# Convert select option value to var

Tags: javascript, html-select, var

So here's my html

```
<select class="form-control" id="citizenType">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
```

and my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value1 = new Array("1","2","3");
  var value2 = new Array("4","5","6");
  function grade(arr) {
    $(arr).each(function(i) {
      $("#grade").append("<option>" + arr[i].value + "</option>");
    });
  };

  $("#citizenType").change(function() {
    var select = $("#citizenType option:selected").val();
    grade(select);
  });
});
```

Why isn't `arr` considered as a variable when passesd in `grade()` ?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but isn't "select" a javascript key word? And if so, you can't use it as your variable name EDIT: Ok, mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `$("#citizenType option:selected").val()` is the literal string `"value1"` or `"value2"`. So when you pass it into the `grade()` function, it is calling `$("value1").each(...)` which will return 0 elements and therefore do nothing. Here's how you can change your code to achieve the result you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {
    value1: new Array("1", "2", "3"),
    value2: new Array("4", "5", "6")
  };

  function grade(arr) {
    $("#grade").empty(); // empty the options list before appending new options
    $.each(arr, function(index, elem) {
      $("#grade").append("<option>" + elem + "</option>");
    });
  };
  $("#citizenType").change(function() {
    var select = $("#citizenType option:selected").val();
    grade(data[select]); // access data[selectedValue] to grab the correct array
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="citizenType">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<select id="grade"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your vars in an object and then access them using bracket notation like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var varWrapper = {
    "value1": new Array("1","2","3"), // accessed using varWrapper["value1"]
    "value2": new Array("4","5","6")  // accessed using varWrapper["value2"]
    // ...
  };
  function grade(arr) {
    // you may consider emptying #grade first using $("#grade").empty()
    // $.each is better for looping arrays and objects
    $.each(arr, function(i, value) {
      $("#grade").append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
    });
  };
  $("#citizenType").change(function() {
    var select = $("#citizenType option:selected").val();
      grade(varWrapper[select]); // access the according variable from varWrapper
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are inside the callback function which can be passedtwo values. The first one is the 'i' value you are using (This is the index of the object in the array) and the second one is the value of the item you are currently acting on, so if you want to iterate over each value and append a option with that value you would need to do something like this:

```
$(arr).each(function(i, value) {
        $("#grade").append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
    });
```

Here is a link to the doc's for this part of the JQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/